# Laravel lavary sidebar menu caching

Tags: php, laravel

how should a Lavary package menu be properly cached?
Whenever I am popping menu from cache, it is not getting assigned globally and my view can not use it, even if I compare actual menu object and cached menu object, they are identical.

Code:

```
 $menu= Cache::get('sidebarMenu');
 if(!$menu) {
    $menu = app(Menu::class);
    $menu->make('sidebarMenu', function ($menu) {
    ....
    //menu creation...
    ....
    Cache::put('sidebarMenu', $menu, 10);
 });
```

If menu is not in cache, it loads fine, but when it is cached, I get an error:

```
Undefined variable: sidebarMenu
```

At view, where it is loaded.

View:

```
@include('partials.menu.sidebar.items', array('items' => $sidebarMenu->roots() ))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you adding the `$sidebarMenu` to the view? I can only see `$menu` in your code.

Comment: @Jerodev updated a code how menu is called from view

Comment: You are still not adding the `$sidebarMenu` to your view anywhere.

Comment: @Jerodev pardon me, but I am a bit confused.

Comment: In your view file you're asking for $sidebarMenu. Now make sure that from your controller you send $sidebarMenu to your view, otherwise you'll get the error that the variable does not exist.